# How append classes dynamically in jquery

Tags: jquery

in one of my variable i have something like 
var x='.myclass'.
Now I want to append this var x while traversing the dom in jQuery.What should be the exact format for that.

Lets say I want to write

```
$("div.myclass a").someoperation();
```

now this .myclass has to dynamic, so I am trying something like

```
$("div"+x+"a").someoperation()
```

but this is not working, any clue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you missed a space here:

```
$("div"+x+" a").someoperation()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div"+x+" a").someoperation();
```

Just missing a space?

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = '.myclass';
$('div' + x + ' a').someoperation();
```

is equivalent to:

```
$('div.myclass a').someoperation();
```

so if the first doesn't work as the second it is because the value of `x` is not `.myclass`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another alternative

where x is "**.myclass**"

```
$('div').find(x).find('a')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x='.'+var_className
$("div"+x+" a").someoperation();
```